# Null values affecting case logic

Tags: mysql, sql

- I am having a problem in the following query.
- In the `AR` column there are some `null` values due to the `left join` of the `wbr_global.raw_station_extended_attribute`.
- To fix this I added a `case` to default to 0 if it is null.
- The issue this is causing is in my next case statement for assinging a station size.
- All the `null` values are pulling in as "ds small" depsite their volume I am pulling in.
- For example, the centroid stations in the picture orignially had `null` as the `ar` value but now have zero but has small pulling in when x-small should be assinged based on the sizing logic.

[image]

```sql
SELECT
    station,

    CASE 
        WHEN ar IS NULL THEN '0'
        ELSE ar
    END AS ar,

    del_date,
    sum( volume ) / 7 AS volume_ref,
    
    DATE_PART("week", del_date) AS week_num,
    DATE_PART("year", del_date) AS year,
    
    CASE 
        WHEN volume_ref between     0 AND 20000 AND ar <> 'YES' THEN 'ds x-small'
        WHEN volume_ref between 20000 AND 36000 AND ar <> 'YES' THEN 'ds small'
        WHEN volume_ref between 36000 AND 42000 AND ar <> 'YES' THEN 'ds standard'
        WHEN volume_ref between 42000 AND 72000 AND ar <> 'YES' THEN 'ds large'
        WHEN volume_ref                 > 72000                 THEN 'ds x-large'
        WHEN                                        ar =  'YES' THEN 'ds x-large'
        ELSE                                                         'ds small'
    END AS station_ref

FROM
    prophecy_na.na_topology_lrp
    LEFT JOIN wbr_global.raw_station_extended_attribute ON 
        prophecy_na.na_topology_lrp.station   = 
        wbr_global.raw_station_extended_attribute.ds 
WHERE
    week_num IN ( 16, 20, 40, 48 )
GROUP BY
    na_topology_lrp.station,
    raw_station_extended_attribute.ar,
    na_topology_lrp.del_date;
```

raw_station_extended_attribute table
[image]

na_topology_lrp table
[image]

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using MySql

Comment: Do you know exactly what version of MySQL you're using - and what the ISO SQL-compliance options are? It looks like you're using column aliases in the same `SELECT`-level, which is a non-standard MySQL SQL extension. Can you also please post the column list of `na_topology_lrp` and `raw_station_extended_attribute `?

Comment: Part of your problem is (I think) that you're using MySQL's "GROUP BY + Unrelated" extension (in addition to MySQL's column alias reference feature) which does result in meaningless data unless you know exactly what you're doing (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html ) - I suggest you refactor your query to do the `GROUP BY` in an inner query and move your derived column expressions to an outer-query or CTE.

Comment: I am not sure of the version as I am consuming it through Dbeaver and not involved in the front end piece.Thank you, I ma not sure how that works. I will post the columns in the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the highlighted row has a station_ref of 'ds small' because of the ELSE statement at the end of the 2nd case statement. Further, you are using multiple 'ar' references here - 'ar' is used to reference the column both *before* and *after* processing the 1st CASE statement.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    station,

    CASE 
        WHEN ar IS NULL THEN '0'
        ELSE ar
    END AS ar,

    del_date,
    sum( volume ) / 7 AS volume_ref,
    
    DATE_PART("week", del_date) AS week_num,
    DATE_PART("year", del_date) AS year,
    
    CASE 
        WHEN volume_ref between     0 AND 20000 AND REPLACE(ar,NULL,'0') <> 'YES' THEN 'ds x-small'
        WHEN volume_ref between 20000 AND 36000 AND REPLACE(ar,NULL,'0') <> 'YES' THEN 'ds small'
        WHEN volume_ref between 36000 AND 42000 AND REPLACE(ar,NULL,'0') <> 'YES' THEN 'ds standard'
        WHEN volume_ref between 42000 AND 72000 AND REPLACE(ar,NULL,'0') <> 'YES' THEN 'ds large'
        WHEN volume_ref                 > 72000                 THEN 'ds x-large'
        WHEN                                        REPLACE(ar,NULL,'0') =  'YES' THEN 'ds x-large'
        ELSE                                                         'ds small'
    END AS station_ref

FROM
    prophecy_na.na_topology_lrp
    LEFT JOIN wbr_global.raw_station_extended_attribute ON 
        prophecy_na.na_topology_lrp.station   = 
        wbr_global.raw_station_extended_attribute.ds 
WHERE
    week_num IN ( 16, 20, 40, 48 )
GROUP BY
    na_topology_lrp.station,
    raw_station_extended_attribute.ar,
    na_topology_lrp.del_date;
```

Comment: Thank you, the issue with that query is most outputs now are showing as ds-small or as x-large but nothing in between . The output does not now match the volume category

Comment: I understand. The assignment of 'ds-small' is occurring because of the ELSE statement at the end of the 2nd CASE statement. Rows that pulled in a NULL ar value are not being properly evaluated here, and are bypassing all WHEN statements and reaching the ELSE statement. I think that using the REPLACE() function in the 2nd CASE statement will resolve that issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, how would you recommend adding that in.

Comment: Note, when the 2nd case statement references the ar column, it is referencing the ar column as it was before it processed by the 1st case statement. So, when the 2nd CASE statement evaluates, it is still finding a NULL, and is unable to compare NULL to 'YES' in a comparison.

Comment: Please use the query I pasted above

Comment: Thank you I used the query above and it is producing the same output.Sorry I am new to SQL so I am unsure how to update it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT station,
isnull(ar,'0') as dsar,
del_date,sum(volume) /7 as volume_ref,DATE_PART("week",del_date) as week_num,DATE_PART("year",del_date) as year,
CASE 
when volume_ref between 0 and 20000 and dsar <> 'YES' then 'ds x-small'
when volume_ref between 20000 and 36000 and dsar <> 'YES' then 'ds small'
when volume_ref between 36000 and 42000 and dsar <> 'YES' then 'ds standard'
when volume_ref between 42000 and 72000 and dsar <> 'YES' then 'ds large'
when volume_ref > 72000 then 'ds x-large'
when dsar = 'YES' then 'ds x-large'
else 'ds small' end as station_ref
FROM prophecy_na.na_topology_lrp
Left JOIN wbr_global.raw_station_extended_attribute ON prophecy_na.na_topology_lrp.station = wbr_global.raw_station_extended_attribute.ds 
where week_num in(16,20,40,48)
Group by na_topology_lrp.station,raw_station_extended_attribute.ar,na_topology_lrp.del_date;
```

Comment: I found using the isnull first was able tot fix it.